# Ignore white spaces in a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to ignore white spaces and parse a pattern like `(int, int) xx (int, int)`. For exemple,

```
import re
m = re.match(r"[\s]*\([\s]*(\d+)[\s]*,[\s]*(\d+)[\s]*\)[\s]*xx[\s]*\([\s]*(\d+)[\s]*,[\s]*(\d+)[\s]*\)[\s]*", "   (2,  74) xx   (5  ,6), physicist")
print (m.group(0)) #    (2,  74) xx   (5  ,6)
print (m.group(1)) # 2
print (m.group(2)) # 74
print (m.group(3)) # 5
print (m.group(4)) # 6
```

As you can see, in my pattern there are lots of `[\s]*` to represent zero or more white spaces. Is there a simpler way to write this pattern?

Comment: You can't get rid of the `\s`, but you can get rid of `[` and `]` around that. Just replace `[\s]` with `\s`.

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the whitespace with `re.sub` and then operate on that string?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a lexer (e.g. `ply`) ? Alternatively, provide some more input/expected output strings.

Comment: Depending on your input you could simply remove any whitespace you find.

Comment: If removing all whitespace doesn't work, you can often make do with Python's built-in tokenizer in the `tokenize` module.

Comment: You probably want [this](https://regex101.com/r/xD8iH9/1) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a method baked into regex, but the easiest solution that comes to mind is using a simple string replace:

```
import re
m = re.match(r"\((\d+),(\d+)\)xx\((\d+),(\d+)\)", "   (2,  74) xx   (5  ,6), physicist".replace(' ', ''))
print (m.group(0)) # (2,74)xx(5,6)
print (m.group(1)) # 2
print (m.group(2)) # 74
print (m.group(3)) # 5
print (m.group(4)) # 6
```

You could also use regex to remove any kind of whitespace (not just spaces):

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'\s+', '', '   (2,  74) xx   (5  ,6), physicist')
m = re.match(r"\((\d+),(\d+)\)xx\((\d+),(\d+)\)", s)
print (m.group(0)) # (2,74)xx(5,6)
print (m.group(1)) # 2
print (m.group(2)) # 74
print (m.group(3)) # 5
print (m.group(4)) # 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Straight forward answer is **NO**. Even they are only white spaces but the fact is they all are characters, thus, they are parts of pattern. I think there are some ways here

1. Preprocess your string by removing unwanted white spaces.
2. Find the another way to express your pattern.
3. Use alternative methods for matching.

e.g.

```
>> re.findall(r'\d+', "   (2,  74) xx   (5  ,6), physicist")
['2', '74', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simplify your **specific** pattern you could eliminate all whitespaces in one separate step before, since they are not relevant for your pattern.

Example:

```
import re
input = '   (2,  74) xx   (5  ,6), physicist'
m = re.match(r"\((\d+),(\d+)\)xx\((\d+),(\d+)\)", input.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: This would be a lot better with an example

Answer (score 2):

I think all you want is to get all the 4 integers, so you can delete all white spaces and then match

```
import re
a = '(  2 , 74 ) xx (5       , 6 )'
b = re.sub(r'\s+','',a)
m = re.match(r'\((\d+),(\d+)\)xx\((\d+),(\d+)\)',b)
print (m.group(0)) # (2,74)xx(5,6)
print (m.group(1)) # 2
print (m.group(2)) # 74
print (m.group(3)) # 5
print (m.group(4)) # 6
```